# Scrollbar positioning based on criteria

Tags: c#, logic, scrollbar

```
A             D              G
B             E              H
C             F
```

Let's imagine the alphabets are image in a panel and there's a vertical scrollbar at the side.
Let's consider the following criteria:

- image onClick event will update scrollbar.value
- minimum value of scrollBar is 0 and maximum value is 100
- image that belongs to the same row will share the same position of the scrollbar

  - A, D, G  : scrollbar.value = 0
  - B, E, H  : scrollbar.value = 50
  - C, F     : scrollbar.value = 100

I've been cracking whole day trying to construct a method to achieve my objective but seems no luck. Couldn't successfully identify which row the image belongs to.

Comment: Is this one image, or multiple images? This is still a bit confusing to understand what you're trying to accomplish. Maybe perhaps add a codepen/jsfiddle, or some sample code of what you've tried so far?

Comment: @FrankerZ: Its multiple images.Basically its about the images on the same row should yield same scrollbar value